# Why does this compile without mutating keyword?

Tags: swift

I feel like something is broken with the value semantics here. Consider:

```
struct A {
    var b = 0
    
    mutating func changeB() {
        b = 6
    }
}

struct B {
    var arr = [A]()
    
    func changeArr() {

        /* as expected this won't compile 
           unlss changeArr() is mutating:
           arr.append(A())
        */

        // but this compiles! despite that changeB is mutating!
        for var a in arr {
            a.changeB()
        }
    }
}
```

Why can this example mutate the struct contents without marking the function as mutating? In true value semantics, any time you change any part of the value, the whole value should be considered changed, and this is usually the behavior in Swift, but in this example it is not. Further, adding a `didSet` observer to `var arr` reveals that `changeArr` is not considered mutation of the value.

Answer (score 2):

```
for var a in arr {
     a.changeB()
}
```

This is copying an element from `arr` out into `a` and leaving `arr` unchanged.

If you directly access the elements inside `arr` via their indexes, then it will mutate and require the `mutating` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The reason changeArr is not mutating is because it isn't really doing anything since it is working on local copies of the A objects. If you really want the method to do something meaningful it needs to be changed to

```
mutating func changeArrForReal() {
    for index in arr.indices {
        arr[index].changeB()
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a tad ironic and amusing that the answer to my question about why the value semantics seem broken is because.. value semantics. :)

Comment: Not related to the question but you should iterate the collection indices. `for index in arr.indices {`. Don't get used to do `0..<arr.count` as not all collections starts from 0 and goes until the last index.